# Finding General Formula for Coefficients of Partial Fractions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I am trying to evaluate the integral as written below and I've tried the following:

> $$\int\prod_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{1}{x-i}\mathrm dx=\int\sum_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{a_i}{x-
> i}\mathrm dx=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i\ln\left| x-i\right|+k, k\in\mathbb{R}$$
>   $$\begin{aligned}a_m=\dfrac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)\cdots\boxed{(x-m)}}=\dfrac{1}{(m-1)(m-2)\cdots1}&=\dfrac{1}{(m-1)!}\\a_1=\dfrac{1}{\boxed{(x-1)}(x-2)\cdots(x-m)}=\dfrac{1}{(-1)(-2)\cdots(1-m)}&=?\end{aligned}$$
>   We could also say that $a_i$ is simply $(x-i)$ divided by $\prod_{i=1}^{m}(x-i)$ at $x=i$. But that itself is not a good starting point to lead to anywhere.

I tried using the Heaviside Cover-Up method to find the $a_i$'s. But I am having a hard time generalizing the rule. **Any hints for finding the general formula for $a_i$ are appreciated**. Thanks

**Edit 1**:

> The expression for $a_1$ can be written in the following form: $$a_1=\dfrac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}$$

**Edit 2**:

> I believe a good guess to the general formula is $$a_i=\dfrac{(-1)^{m-i}}{(m-i)!}$$

Comment: Also $a_2=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-2)!}$

Comment: That indeed can be accommodated in $a_i=(-1)^{m-i}/(m-i)!$. Is that the correct answer?

Comment: No because $a_{m-i}=-a_i$

Answer (score 1):

We may write  $$ a_i = \frac {1}{ \Pi _{1\le j\ne i \le m} (i-j)}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering Prof. I have already included this in the OP. I was looking for a closed form expression for $a_i$ that somehow involves maybe factorials or other elementary functions. :)